# Mixed SLURM Cluster using Centos7 and Debian8

Tags: cluster-computing, centos7, slurm, debian-jessie, queuing

I am using SLURM on a Centos7 cluster.

Is it possible to get SLURM working with various OSes (for example Centos7 and Debian8) on the same cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Slurm will run, but beware that programs compiled on one OS will not necessarily function on the other OS.

Comment: Yes that was actually the reason why i planned to do it. But then i found a way to install those programs at Centos. Thanks anyway!